# EntityFramework 6 Table per Hierarchy (inheritance)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Hi I have a class that has multiple inheritance.
I wrote this code before EF5 (EF Core 2 or 3) and I just upgraded to EF6 right now.
Here is the table. I have `Entitlement` as parent class, and it has many children classes.
Some class has similiar fields like in `AnnualLeaveEntitlement` and `SickLeaveEntitlement`. they are similiar fields but I made separated one.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CRSApp.API.Models
{
    public class Entitlement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }      
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")] 
        public string Name {get; set;}
        [Column(TypeName="varchar(200)")]  
        public string TypeOfLeave {get; set;} 
        public bool isShownOnPaySlip {get; set;}

        public string EntitlementType {
        get {
            return this.GetType().Name;
        }
}
    }

    public class AnnualLeaveEntitlement : Entitlement
    {
        public decimal Duration { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="varchar(20)")]
        public string DurationType { get; set; } // weeks days years hours etc
        public decimal AccrualRate { get; set; } 

    }

    public class SickLeaveEntitlement : Entitlement
    {
        public decimal Duration { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="varchar(20)")]
        public string DurationType { get; set; } // weeks days years hours etc
        public decimal AccrualRate { get; set; } 

    }

    public class LongServiceLeaveEntitlement : Entitlement
    {
        public decimal YearsOfEmployment { get; set; }
        public decimal Duration { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="varchar(20)")]
        public string DurationType { get; set; } // weeks days years hours etc
        public decimal AccrualRate { get; set; } 

    }

    public class CompasionateLeaveEntitlement : Entitlement
    {
        public decimal Duration { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="varchar(20)")]
        public string DurationType { get; set; } // weeks days years hours etc

    }

    public class JuryDutyLeaveEntitlement : Entitlement
    {
        public string Description {get; set;}
    }

    public class StudyLeaveEntitlement : Entitlement
    {
        public decimal Duration { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName="varchar(20)")]
        public string DurationType { get; set; } // weeks days years hours etc

    }

    public class UnpaidLeaveEntitlement : Entitlement
    {
        public string Description {get; set;}
    }

    public class OtherLeaveEntitlement: Entitlement
    {
        public string Description  {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Now I generate this table into migrations:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Entitlement",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(200)", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            TypeOfLeave = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(200)", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            isShownOnPaySlip = table.Column<bool>(type: "tinyint(1)", nullable: false),
            Discriminator = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            AnnualLeaveEntitlement_Duration = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            AnnualLeaveEntitlement_DurationType = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(20)", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            AccrualRate = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            Duration = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            DurationType = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(20)", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            Description = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            YearsOfEmployment = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            LongServiceLeaveEntitlement_Duration = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            LongServiceLeaveEntitlement_DurationType = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(20)", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            LongServiceLeaveEntitlement_AccrualRate = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            OtherLeaveEntitlement_Description = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            SickLeaveEntitlement_Duration = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            SickLeaveEntitlement_DurationType = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(20)", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            SickLeaveEntitlement_AccrualRate = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            StudyLeaveEntitlement_Duration = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(65,30)", nullable: true),
            StudyLeaveEntitlement_DurationType = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(20)", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
            UnpaidLeaveEntitlement_Description = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Entitlement", x => x.Id);
        })
        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");
```

But it generated "inconsistent" field, like `AnnualLeave`, `Sickleave` they are generated with `AnnualLeave_Duration` and `SickLeave_Duration`, but for `CompasionatedLeave` the migratos just generate `Duration` and `DurationType` field

Does this normal ? Should I migrate to use TPT instead TPH for this case ?

I also need to query all Entitlements sometimes, how to do that with TPH ?

Thank you

note: I use EF Core 6.0.8 and Dotnet 6.0.8. Mysql 8 for database.

Comment: What is your intent for fields in the derived entities with the same name and type - to have separate columns in the (in TPH, single) table as shown, or common columns? It has nothing to do with querying capabilities, just the storage and how they are queried.

Comment: thanks for comment. if TPT can I do query all Entitlement ?

also I wonder why CompasionateLeaveEntitlement doesnt have CompasionateLeaveEntitlement _Duration ? instead they generate Duration. it is confusing actually

Comment: (1) You can query all Entitlement in both TPH and TPT, that's the whole idea. The difference is that TPT will create separate table for each derived entity. (2) Yeah, looks confusing to me as well. But this is how they did it. Event though you can change associated table column names as you wish, as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#shared-columns)

Comment: EF 6 and EF Core 6 are two completely different frameworks. Which one exactly do you use? Edit the title and body of the question, delete the irrelevant tag.

Comment: If you manually specify the column names, the properties from the child types can be mapped to the same database column.